# Factoring and solving trinomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, algorithms, factorization

Has the problem of factoring (over the rationals) the general trinomial $ax^n+bx^k+c$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n,k\in\mathbb{N}, n>k>1$ been solved?  By *solved* I mean a classification theorem which will either give the factors or give a certificate that it is irreducible.

One could ask the same question, but about finding *expressions* for the roots of a trinomial.  I am aware that [long ago](http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/timeline.html) this problem was worked on, but I have been unable to find a modern treatment of this problem.

The question which actually motivates this one is: given a trinomial which factors, consider the *number of terms* in each of the factors.  Further, assume that the trinomial is **not** cyclotomic.  How many terms can the factors have?  [The cyclotomic case is conjectured to be special].

[Edit: clarified that I am interested in this special case, not the general case, where the algorithms of M. van Hoeij are the current best, much superior to Cantor-Zassenhaus].

Comment: I am curious about the question/conjecture that you mention at the end: would you mind giving more details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can of course apply general algorithms for irreducibility testing and factorization, so I presume you are asking if there is something more efficient or more explicit that can be said in the case of trinomials. Except for special cases I don't believe that is the case.

While it is known that every binomial in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ must have an irreducible factor that is either binomial or trinomial, no analogous bound is known in the trinomial case. It is at least 8 terms due to the [known [1]](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayFulltext?type=1&fid=5054152&jid=GMJ&volumeId=34&issueId=01&aid=5054144) example

$$f(x)f(-x) = - x^{14} - 27180501562500 x^2 + 1244325625000000$$

for $f(x) = x^7 + 20 x^6 + 200 x^5 + 2450 x^4 + 29000 x^3 + 545000 x^2 + 8101250 x + 35275000$

[1](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayFulltext?type=1&fid=5054152&jid=GMJ&volumeId=34&issueId=01&aid=5054144) Choudhry and A. Schinzel (1992).
On the number of terms in the irreducible factors of a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.
Glasgow Mathematical Journal (1992), 34, 11-15.

To dig deeper I suggest starting with the work of Schinzel - who has studied these and related factorization problems intensively for almost half a century, e.g. see

> MR1254093 (95d:11146) 11R09 (12E05 12E10)
>   Schinzel, Andrzej. 
>   On reducible trinomials.
>   Dissertationes Math. (Rozprawy Mat.) 329 (1993), 83 pp.
>
> Let $K$ be a field. It is well known
>   that a binomial $x^n+a\in K[x]$ is
>   reducible iff it has the form
>   $x^{pk}-b^p$ ($p$ prime) or
>   $x^{4k}+4b^4$. In this treatise the
>   reducibility of trinomials
>   $x^n+ax^m+b$ $(a,b\neq 0)$ is
>   investigated. It turns out that the
>   situation is very complicated. A
>   satisfactory answer is obtained if $K$
>   is a rational function field. For
>   algebraic function fields in one
>   variable and for algebraic number
>   fields, less complete results are
>   proved. It is assumed throughout that
>   the characteristic of $K$ does not
>   divide $mn(n-m)$.
>
> It is easy to find trinomials with
>   linear or quadratic factors. Table 1
>   of this paper provides additional
>   families of reducible trinomials if
>   $(n,m)$ belongs to a list of 12 pairs,
>   the largest being $(15,5)$. Perhaps
>   the simplest example is
>   $$x^6+4(v+1)x^2-v^2=(x^3+2x^2+2x-v)(x^3-2x^2+2x+v).$$ Every reducible trinomial
>   $f(x)=x^n+ax^m+b$ gives rise to
>   additional examples by considering
>   $u^nf(x^l/u)$ (with $u\in K^\times$
>   and $l\geq 1$) or $x^nf(1/x)/b$.
>   Theorem 1 essentially states that
>   every reducible trinomial arises in
>   this manner from the examples
>   indicated before if $K$ is a rational
>   function field. (More precisely, it is
>   assumed that $a^{-n}b^{n-m}$ is not a
>   constant.) Table 2 lists $7$ families
>   of reducible trinomials
>   $x^n+A(v,w)x^m+B(v,w)$ with $(v,w)\in
> > E(K)$, where $A$, $B$ are polynomials
>   over $\mathbb Z$ and $E$ is an
>   elliptic curve defined by an equation
>   $z^2=C(w)$, where $C$ is a monic
>   polynomial over $\mathbb Z$. The
>   polynomials $A,B$ and the
>   corresponding factorizations of the
>   trinomials are too complicated to be
>   included in this review. (For the
>   largest pair $(n,m)=(21,7)$ the
>   corresponding $A$ fills 10 lines in
>   the paper.) In Theorem 2 it is assumed
>   that $K$ is a finite extension of a
>   rational function field $F(t)$ such
>   that $\overline FK$ has genus $g>0$
>   and $a^{-n}b^{n-m}\notin
> > \overline{F}$. If $g=1$ then there are
>   no additional examples of reducible
>   trinomials. If $g>1$ then essentially
>   new examples with $n<24g$ may exist.
>   Theorem 3 reduces the case where $K$
>   is a finite separable extension of
>   $F(t)$ and $a^{-n}b^{n-m}\in\overline
> > F$ to studying reducibility over
>   $K\cap\overline F$. If $K$ is an
>   algebraic number field then for fixed
>   $n$, $m$ a finite number of
>   essentially new examples of reducible
>   trinomials $x^n+ax^m+b$ may exist
>   (Theorem 6). The author conjectures
>   that for every $K$ there is only a
>   finite number of these ``sporadic
>   trinomials''. If the conjecture holds
>   then there exists a constant $c(K)$
>   such that every trinomial over $K$ has
>   an irreducible factor with at most
>   $c(K)$ nonzero coefficients
>   (Consequence 2). Table 5 contains all
>   52 sporadic trinomials over $\mathbb
> > Q$ known to the author. Their degrees
>   lie in the range from $8$ to $52$. The
>   rest of the paper is devoted to
>   studying the reducibility of
>   $ax^n+bx^m+c\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Theorem
>   9 (refining a result of Nagell)
>   derives necessary conditions, which in
>   the case $(m,n)=1$ yield an explicit
>   bound for $b$ in terms of $a,c,m,n$.
>   For every positive integer $d$ there
>   exist only finitely many $n,m,b$ with
>   $n/(m,n)>d$ and $|b|>2$ such that
>   $x^n+bx^m\pm 1$ has a factor of degree
>   $d$; and these can be effectively
>   computed. Theorem 10 derives necessary
>   conditions from the existence of a
>   factor (of $ax^n+bx^m+c)$ of given
>   degree $d$. These imply that there
>   exists $n_0(d)$ such that $x^n+bx^m+1$
>   is irreducible if $n\geq n_0(d)$,
>   $n\neq 2m$, $|b|>2$. By Theorem 8, for
>   every $n$ there exist only finitely
>   many reducible trinomials $x^n+bx^m+1$
>   with $n\neq 2m$.
>
> The proof of Theorem 10 does not
>   depend on the other results of the
>   paper. The same applies to Theorem 9.
>   All other theorems except for Theorem
>   3 are based on lower estimates for the
>   genus of certain function fields.
>   These estimates show that the
>   existence of a factor of degree $k$ of
>   $x^n+ax^m+b\in K[x]$ imposes severe
>   restrictions on $k,m,n,a,b$ provided
>   $K$ is a function field. The remaining
>   cases are treated in a long series of
>   lemmas applying to every field $K$
>   whose characteristic does not divide
>   $mn(n-m)$. In several cases the proofs
>   require extensive manipulations (with
>   polynomials in several variables)
>   which were performed by means of
>   computer algebra systems. Faltings'
>   theorem (solving Mordell's conjecture)
>   is invoked in the proof of Theorem 6
>   (dealing with number fields). Theorems
>   7 and 8 (concerning
>   $ax^n+bx^m+c\in\mathbb Z[x])$ are
>   proved by using the corresponding
>   theorems for rational function fields
>   together with a lemma which may be
>   viewed as a refinement of Hilbert's
>   irreducibility theorem. The proof of
>   this lemma is based on Siegel's
>   theorem (on integral points of curves
>   of positive genus) and on a result of
>   Maillet (1919) dealing with rational
>   functions over $\mathbb Q$ taking
>   infinitely many integral values at
>   rational points.
>
> {Reviewer's remarks: In Theorem 2 the
>   term $u^{\nu-\mu}$ in the expression
>   for $B$ has to be replaced by $u^\nu$.
>   The proof of Lemma 27 employs Lemma
>   2(c) although this lemma only applies
>   to separable extensions. In order to
>   prove Lemma 49 one has to know that
>   every finite separable extension $L$
>   of $K(t)$ with $L\subseteq \overline
> > K(t)$ is contained in $K'(t)$ for some
>   separable extension $K'$ of $K$. (One
>   can in fact prove that $L=K'(t)$ for
>   suitable $K'$. This need not be true
>   for inseparable $L$.) The proof of
>   Theorem 6 is apparently based on the
>   incorrect assumption that a divisor
>   $P$ of a function field $L=K(t,y)$ has
>   degree $1$ or is ramified with respect
>   to $K(t)$ if $t$ and $y$ are congruent
>   to elements of $K\bmod P$.}
>
> REVISED (1995)
>
> Reviewed by G. Turnwald

Comment: Excellent.  I was aware of some of Schinzel's work on this, but not those particular papers.

Answer (score 1):

Factor where? Over the rationals? Take a look to Berlekamp algorith. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm

The right link is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm
to Berlekamp–Zassenhaus algorithm.

Comment: Well, I meant rationals but I should maybe edit to put the right link to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm

Berlekamp–Zassenhaus algorithm

Comment: See my edits.  Computer algebra is one of my areas of expertize, so I am rather familiar with the work you mention already.  So I have edited my question to make it clearer what I am looking for.

Comment: No idea then. I have no areas of expertize.